# NAS license other than in database

Tags: dynamics-nav, navision

I have a Nav database with license "A" **saved in it**. License "A" does not allow read of certain tables (Job Queue).

Is it possible to run NAS (navision application server) under another license "B" which allows access to the objects I need?

Simply changing `fin.flf` in NAS installation folder to license "B" is not working. In this case NAS still using license "A" saved in database.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to look at doing this depending on your ability and access to modify code within the system.

One such method is detailed by Kirki that involves changing how the licensing is stored in the database it self; and is a bit of a breaking change in how you manage the license files.

[How to use multiple licenses simultaneously in service tier and development (and classic) environment](http://www.mibuso.com/howtoinfo.asp?FileID=23)

Normally in a production database you would want to control this with Security on the relevant tables and users as opposed to having multiple license files; which should be much easier to accomplish and does not require any special development.

Comment: Thank you. That is definitely the way, but it is too _heavy_ for my current task. For my task it will be easier to move tables to another range and use them with current license.